# solution for errors appear on LogCat in Android

Tags: android, eclipse, runtime-error, android-logcat

I added google API with some markers on it to my android application. when I run the application it runs perfectly as usual. i.e. it runs like before adding the map. but it opens the LogCat with some errors. I search to solve the errors but I didn't reach a solution.
Note: these errors sometimes appear (Not Always).
here are the errors that appear on the LogCat

```
03-08 11:51:40.247: I/Icing(950): Storage manager: low false usage 9.34KB avail 99.15MB capacity 167.55MB
03-08 11:51:40.437: E/Icing(950): Error initializing, resetting corpora: Could not create native index
03-08 11:51:40.567: E/Icing(950): Internal init failed
03-08 11:51:40.567: E/Icing(950): Couldn't handle android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED intent due to initialization failure.
03-08 11:51:41.147: D/PackageBroadcastService(950): Received broadcast action=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED and uri=com.project.sbms
03-08 11:51:41.387: E/Icing(950): Couldn't handle android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED intent due to initialization failure.
03-08 11:51:41.747: D/dalvikvm(950): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 282K, 25% free 3135K/4164K, paused 37ms, total 40ms
03-08 11:51:41.787: I/PeopleContactsSync(950): CP2 sync disabled
03-08 11:51:42.937: D/PackageBroadcastService(950): Received broadcast action=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED and uri=com.project.sbms
03-08 11:51:43.017: I/PeopleContactsSync(950): CP2 sync disabled
03-08 11:51:43.027: E/Icing(950): Couldn't handle android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED intent due to initialization failure.
```

Could anyone please help me find a solution..

Thanks..

Comment: These error seen in the above does not relate Location relater/google maps api related.Some how system is not able to handle the application installed